# how to get avd name of running android emulators in command line?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, adb

adb devices only give the emulator id. like

```
List of devices attached 
emulator-5554   device
```

But in eclipse 'Android Device Choose' the avd name(e.g, 2.3) is listed. How to get the info in command line?
[image]
Thanks

Comment: @Nikkajihaikjawak please use more restraint in editing questions.  Removing from the title the fact that it was specifically the avd name that was sought made the question less clear.